# Why is my django group showing an empty Queryset

Tags: python, django, django-request

I have this project and I want to be able to allow only members in a particular group to view it. But the problem is that in my admin panel, there are two groups there but when I run

```
 request.user.groups.all()
```

I get an empty list?

I'm using django 3.2

Comment: It means that your logged in user, is not a member of any groups.

Comment: I logged in as an admin and still it was showing an empty Queryset

Comment: an admin does not (per se) belongs to any group either. It is a `User` with `is_superuser` set on `True`.

Comment: Oooh ok. So I have to add the admin to the group from the admin panel?

Comment: you can make use of the Django admin site (if you added these) to create groups and add users to these groups.

Comment: I created two groups, one for admin and one for customers and I just realized that the admin's section is empty. Thanks for your contribution